# Error generating client certificate using openssl

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority, x509

Getting this error with openssl 1.1.1d when using the CA generated as shown:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -config ca.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out ca-certificate.pem -outform PEM
openssl req -new -config client.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -out client-certificate.csr -outform PEM
openssl ca -batch -config ca.cnf -policy signing_policy -extensions signing_req -out client-certificate.pem -infiles client-certificate.csr
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client-certificate.pem -inkey client-private-key.pem -password pass:xxx -chain -CAfile ca-certificate.pem -out client.p12 -name "Client Certificate"
Error invalid ca certificate getting chain
```

This works fine with v1.0.2.
Please advise if there's a work-around.

Comment: Please clarify your question, e.g. by adding the CA and client certificates (`openssl x509 -in <cert_file> -noout -text`). I can confirm certificate signing works with OpenSSL 1.1.1d, so there is something wrong in your procedure.

Comment: Is `client-certificate.pem` signed by the CA certificate?  I suspect not as you haven't saved the CA's private key (which is required to sign) in the first step of your process.

Comment: Edited for full commands used. If the ca.cnf is required, I can post that too. I left it out because it's quite big.